# How to conditionally modify string values in dataframe column - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe of which one column ('entity) contains various names of countries and non-state entities. I need to clean the column because the string values (provided by manual data-entry) are all lower-case (china instead of China). I can't just perform the .title() operation on the column since there are string values for which I want nothing to done (e.g., al Something should not be turned into AL Something).

I'm have trouble creating a function to help me with this problem and could use some guidance from the community. In the past I've used dictionaries to help map/replace incorrect strings with correct strings, and I can still revert to that way of doing things, but I thought creating this function might be more straightforward and efficient and plus I wanted to challenge myself. But no changes occurs to the entity column when I execute the function. Thanks in advance!

```
myString = ['al Group1', 'al Group2']

entities = df['entity']
def title_fix(entities):
    new_titles = []
    for entity in entities:
        if entity in myString:
            new_titles.append(myString)
        else:
           new_title.append(entity.title())
        return new_title

title_fix(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entities` in the line `entities = df['entity']` is *not the same variable* as the `entities` in the line `def title_fix(entities):`. This second `entities` variable is the argument to the function `title_fix`, and it exists only within the function. It takes on whatever argument you pass into your call to `title_fix`, which is `df`.

Try this instead of your function:

```
# A list of entity names to leave alone (must exactly match character-for-character)
myString = ['al Group1', 'al Group2']
# Apply title case to every entity NOT in myString
df['entity'] = df['entity'].apply(lambda x: x if x in myString else x.title())
# Print the modified DataFrame
df
```

Note that this solution requires that each string in `myString` *exactly* matches the target string in `df['entity']`, otherwise the target string will not be replaced.

Comment: this works! thank you for taking the time. I didn't think of using a lambda function, but will start thinking of incorporating in my work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code had several bugs, such as spelling and indentation. Fixed code:

```
myString = ['al Group1', 'al Group2']
entities = df['entity']

def title_fix(entities):
    new_titles = []
    for entity in entities:
        if entity in myString:
            new_titles.append(entity)
        else:
            new_titles.append(entity.title())
    return new_titles

df['entity'] = title_fix(entities)
```

However, what you want to achieve can be done in a one-liner. I came up with 3 solutions. I don't know pandas that well and I have no idea about the performance differences between these solutions, but here they are.

`ignored` makes a little bit more sense than `myString` so I'll use it.

```
ignored = ['al Group1', 'al Group2']
```

First solution:

```
df['entity'] = df['entity'].apply(lambda x: x.title() if x not in ignored else x)
```

Second:

```
df.entity[~df.entity.isin(ignored)] = df.entity.str.title()
```

Third:

```
df.loc[~df.entity.isin(ignored), 'entity'] = df.entity.str.title()
```

Comment: thank you so much - the lambda function makes a lot a sense to e as well as your other potential solutions.